# How can I sniff whole network in Scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy, libpcap, packet-sniffers

When I use Scapy,It sniffs only my local machine traffic. How can I sniff whole the local network? I set my network adapter mode to Monitoring mode and also enable port forwarding. But still It can't sniff another client on the network. Do I have to ARP Poisoning? 
The command I use:

```
pkts = sniff(iface="wlan0", filter="icmp")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should redirect others devices traffic to your device then,start sniffing.